# Error al instalar plataforma XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Quisiera que me ayudaran con este problema. Casi al final de la instalación de XAMPP me sale el siguiente error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\web\vendor\doctrine\annotations\lib\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException.php on line 54

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Verifico esa ruta y me muestra estas líneas de código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Sé que puede sonar tonto pero... Ese pedazo de código parece estar funcionando para lo que debe: Mostrar un error, en éste caso, un error semantical oséase, un error en la expresión.
Seguiste un procedimiento estándar de instalación para XAMPP?

Comment: El tema con xampp, creo que no tiene ningún problema ya que tengo alojado 2 paginas web de instituto y colegio y funciona normal, el único cambio que realice fue de variar el puerto 80 a 8080, es todo.

Comment: Lo mejor que te puedo ofrecer, es [éste post en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103924/xampp-port-80-is-busy-easyphp-error-in-apache-configuration-file) que trata de cómo liberar el puerto 80, y también [éste otro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552306/how-to-change-the-port-number-of-apache-in-xampp). Lo siento, ahorita me anda horrible la computadora, cuando pueda trataré de ayudarte más :). Suerte

Comment: No sé si esto es algo que pueda ayudarte, pero parece que es un problema que ocurre al instalar chamilo en Windows con MySQL y hay un parche para solucionarlo. Mira este enlace: https://github.com/chamilo/chamilo-lms/issues/2018 a ver si te sirve

Comment: Alvaro Montoro, muchas gracias. solucione mi problema gracias a ese link. agradecido enormemente. (y)